# Getting symbol information for value held in GDB convenience variable

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I often find it useful to walk the stack when I'm debugging a program and get the symbols for any properly aligned, pointer-sized value I encounter.  I've gotten sick of doing this manually and so I tried writing a command that does it for me.  The problem is that "info symbol" doesn't seem to like using a convenience variable as its parameter when its parameter was set via pointer dereference. IE:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0xb6ca4d28
[Useful Symbol Information]
(gdb) set $pointer = $esp
(gdb) while ( *(int*)$pointer != 0xb6ca4d28)
 >set $pointer += 4
 >end
(gdb) x/x $pointer
0x6ebee064:     0xb6ca4d28
(gdb) set $dereferencePointer = *(int *)$pointer
(gdb) p/x $dereferencePointer
$103 = 0xb6ca4d28
(gdb) info symbol $dereferencePointer
No symbol matches $dereferencePointer.
(gdb) set $dereferencePointer = 0xb6ca4d28
(gdb) p/x $dereferencePointer
$104 = 0xb6ca4d28
(gdb) info symbol $dereferencePointer
[Useful symbol information]
(gdb)
```

Why is this?  Is this a bug?  Is there a different way to do this?

Thanks!

Luc

PS: Using vanilla GDB 7.5

**Update from list:**

This is most likely a bug.

Comment: Maybe a `gdb` related mailing list could be a better place to ask.

Comment: To follow up: Having not found a gdb equivalent of freebsd-questions, I did post this question to general gdb list and have yet to get a response.  If I do, I will update the question.

Comment: For the record, this seems to work fine on `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20111117-cvs-debian`

Answer (score 1):

Bug or not, I recommend using the /a format specifier with p and x commands. This always works for me, and is faster to type, too.